# How to make a macro to name worksheet names from a list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Currently I have code which grabs each work sheet name consecutively and puts it into a list. What I want is a code that will read the names in the list on the first work sheet and rename each page in the worksheet consecutively.

```
Sub ListWorkSheetNamesNewWs()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xTitleId = "TabNames"
Application.Sheets(xTitleId).Delete
Application.Sheets.Add Application.Sheets(1)
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Name = xTitleId
For i = 2 To Application.Sheets.Count
    xWs.Range("A" & (i - 1)) = Application.Sheets(i).Name
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RenameSheets()
    For i = 1 To 200
        On Error Resume Next
        oldname = Cells(i, 3).Value
        newname = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Sheets(oldname).Name = newname
    Next
End Sub
```

Place Old Names from C1 down, Place New Names in B1 down.